# CSS and first-child

Tags: css

In CSS, I select "first-child". I want only `<div class="b">1</div>` on red background. I don't understand

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.a .b:first-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">1</div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="b">2</div>
    <div class="b">3</div>
    <div class="b">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: because `.b` is the `:first-child` of `.a` and of `.c` so they both have red backgrounds. You really only use `:first-child` to distinguish among sibling elements, you want the `.a > .b` for your markup

Answer (score 1):

`.a .b:first-child` means any `.b:first-child` that is a descendant of `.a`.  Space is the descendant combinator; it doesn't link `:first-child` to `.a` in any way.

You want a direct child of `.a`, using the child combinator: `.a > .b`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want your `first-child` pseudo-class on `.a`, not `.b`.

```css
div {
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}

.a:first-child {
  background: red
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <div class="b">1</div>
  <div class="c">
    <div class="b">2</div>
    <div class="b">3</div>
    <div class="b">4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```